# How to zip the results folder, after running tests through Jenkins and send email notification

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy

After running test in jenkins, results will be under test-output folder with multiple files, wants to zip the folder and send email notification.

Test Results will be in the path : `**/test-output/html`.

To send the results through email, code snippet will be as:

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/test-output/html/*', body: '${JOB_NAME} - ${BUILD_NUMBER} - manual log', mimeType: 'text/plain', replyTo: ‘user1@gmail.com’, subject: '${JOB_NAME} - ${BUILD_NUMBER} - manual log', to: ‘user2@gmail.com user3@gmail.com’
```

Above command will send all the files in `html` folder but i want to send them in a zip folder.

can anyone help me, how to zip the folder using groovy script.